# Annotation in UIWebview in iphone sdk

Tags: uiwebview, annotations, core-graphics, touches

I need help for, scribbling on the webpage i.e where ever the user moves on the uiwebview there it should draw a line according to the touch moves.

Is this possible.

Can any one please help me in this.

Thanks,
Mrudula.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible just you have to write uiWebView.scrollView instead of uiWebView for getting coordinates of uiwebview.

Answer (score -1):

I started working on something sort of like this. It doesn't currently let you "draw", but it does let you detect and record relative touch coordinates so that you can scale them correctly when zooming in. The DSAnnotationView object lets you provide a custom UIView to be toggled at the annotation point. Check it out here: https://github.com/justindarc/WebViewAnnotations

-Justin